# Taking elements from queues

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a way to calculate the total amount of possibilities to merge elements from two stacks into one?

Say I got a stack with A, B, C and one with D, E. You can always only take the leftmost element of each stack to form one new stack with 5 entries.

I think I end up with ten:
A   B   C   D   E
A   B   D   C   E
A   B   D   E   C
A   D   B   C   E
A   D   B   E   C
A   D   E   B   C
D   E   A   B   C
D   A   E   B   C
D   A   B   E   C
D   A   B   C   E

Is there a way to calculate that number? It is not permutations, it is not combinations (or is it?!?)...

If my 10 entries above were correct a multiplication formula can only be 2 * 5 obviously... but I have no idea how to get to the 5... except... 3 elements in the one stack, 2 in the other... makes 5.

Number of stacks x sum(all stack amounts) ?? Is it that simple, always? With 3 or 4 stacks also?

Comment: You have to pick 5 entries in total, three of those have to be from the first stack. Thus you distribute three "pick from stack one" on five places. (${n \choose k} ={ 5 \choose 3} = 10$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the stacks have sizes $m$ and $n$. The merged stack has $m+n$ positions, and once you know which $m$ of them contain the members of the first stack, you know the entire contents, since the order within the stacks is fixed. Thus, there are $\binom{m+n}m=\binom{m+n}n$ possible merged stacks.

In your example it’s $\binom{3+2}3=\binom53=10$.